# Irritating noise from Galaxy Note s%

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

How can I find out which program or app is causing the 'bottle opener' sound on my Galaxy Note s5?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming there is nothing showing up in the notifications bar to let you know what wants your attention.

I would open up a system monitoring app (like OS monitor) and check to see what has recently accessed services.  If an app doesn't jump out on its own, you can then sleuth backwards with Permissions Explorer and see what is tapping the service to give you the notification.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is check my settings to see what apps I have open, and then I check all of those apps to see what app is doing it. Otherwise, you may have to reboot it.